# Graphing the compound interest formula correctly

Tags: plotting, function-construction, finance

To preface, I'm very, very new to Mathematica.
I've written a few functions to calculate compound dividends from stocks.

```
compoundDivsInterest[shares_, divyield_, years_, compoundrate_] := 
   ((shares (1 + (divyield/compoundrate))^(compoundrate*years) - shares))

compoundDivsTotal[shares_, divyield_, years_,compoundrate_] := 
   ((shares (1 + (compoundrate))^(compoundrate*years)))
```

TL;DR: I can't seem to get these functions to graph their correct exponential form. I've tried using a sum, using `Show[Table[Plot[...`, `For[...Plot[...`, and a "recursive" function. None have worked so far.
What should I do to get them to plot correctly?

As they are now, they will give the right value for a given x, but any other values are incorrect (as the function doesn't technically compound off the new principal). 
If I graph the functions, they are linear in nature.

A friend better versed in Mathematica than I suggested I use a sum to graph them. 
`Plot[Sum[compoundDivsTotal[x, 0.0659, 1, 4], {x, 1, n, 1}],{n, 0,1000}]`

This does yield an exponential curve as would be expected, but none of the values are correct.

In order to plot the correct, exponential graph of compounded interest, I figured it would probably have to be done recursively or iteratively. I've tried many different ways from google, such as `Show[Table[Plot[...`, and `For[...Plot[...`.
Finally, I tried doing the closest thing I could find to recursion, which was to re-implement the function as:

```
recCompoundDivsTotal[shares_,divyield_,years_,compoundrate_] := 
 recCompoundDivsTotal[shares] = 
   ((shares (1 +(divyield/compoundrate))^(compoundrate * years)))
```

It gives the right value, but it's still linear in nature even though, from what I understand, it ought to recursively iterate using the previous value of `shares`

I'm at a loss for what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the parameters `divyield`?

Comment: It's the dividend yield of the stock as a decimal percentage. In effect, the interest rate of the stock.

Comment: And `divyield=`?

Comment: My bad. Use .0659. I've been calling the function using `compoundDivsTotal[x, 0.0659, 1, 4]`

Comment: So `compoundrate = 4`? It's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is an option if the functions are defined correctly.

```
compoundDivsInterest[shares_, divyield_, years_, 
      compoundrate_] := ((shares (1 + (divyield/
              compoundrate))^(compoundrate*years) - shares))

compoundDivsTotal[shares_, divyield_, years_, 
  compoundrate_] := ((shares (1 + (compoundrate))^(compoundrate*
       years)))

{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[compoundDivsTotal[10^n, 0.0659, t, .4], {n, 2, 3}]], {t, 0, 
   10}, AxesLabel -> {"t, years", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Compound Dividends Total", PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[
   Table[compoundDivsTotal[s, 0.0659, t, .4], {n, 2, 3}]], {t, 0, 
   10}, {s, 0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"t, years", "shares", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Compound Dividends Total", Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

[image: fig1]